# How to concatenate the response of 2 where clause calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to return a collection of users, and combine the results of 2 different queries.

I currently have this but I am not seeing correct results

```
def get_abc()
  users = User.where("....")
  users << User.where("...")
  users
end
```

Is this the correct way to combine the results of 2 different queries?

Comment: does this where are based on any condition? Do you need uniq records? Is it related to some sort of filters? I am asking this because each of this will have a different aspect of query

Comment: Doing `users << User.where("...")` might give you duplicate records. Better to use `|=` here.

Comment: "I am not seeing correct results" - the question is not clear. You are not getting the correct result and you also want to combine the 2 queries together. First you need to fix the code to return correct result.

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume your two queries be like this, then:

```
first_names = User.where(:first_name => 'Tobias') # ActiveRecord::Relation
last_names  = User.where(:last_name  => 'Fünke') # ActiveRecord::Relation
```

If you want to combine using AND (intersection), use merge:

```
first_names.merge(last_names)
```

If you want to combine using OR (union), use or (available in ActiveRecord 5+, or in 4.2 via where-or backport):

```
first_names.or(last_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is related to some sort of filter then you should not use your this approach as it will have redundant data. Next worst thing is you are firing multiple queries to fetch user data. Instead of doing this you can go with different approaches.
With query string

```
condition = "first_name = :first_name "
attributes = { first_name: 'xyz'}
condition = " And/Or last_name = :lastname" if your_other_condition?
attributes[:lastname] = 'abc'
users = User.where(condition, attributes)
```

The other way can be with help of scopes (I suppose you are filtering data)

```
users = User.where("...")
users = users.scope1 if any condition
```

It will lastly use query and will return you desired data.

Comment: He is not filtering the results of 1st query. Instead adding the results of second query to the first.